# Comparing two Mats of same size and creating a 3rd Mat having max values of each element

Tags: opencv

Is there any function for copying only max values from 2 Mats in the third e.g.

```
Mat m1;
Mat m2;
Mat result;
copy_max_only( m1, m2, result )
```

so that result contains for each element only max of corresponding element of m1 or m2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`cv::max()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=compare#max) function:

```
cv::Mat result = cv::max(m1,m2);
```